# Visual editor not working after update

Tags: errors, visual-editor

After update wordpress visual editor are blank.
[image: Visual editor error]

I tried disabling all plugins, changing theme to 2014, and cleaning cache in server and pc. (not working)

Comment: What about a vanilla install of the same version of WordPress on the same machine?  Does that work?  Something could have gone wrong during the update, it may be as simple as reuploading the core files.

Comment: I copy files from backup before update. I run it on my own home server and update it. All works. This don't works on amazon servers.